# Understanding Binomial sums and general question about analysis

Tags: analysis, binomial-coefficients

I've started Analysis I in the University few weeks ago, and I find it really complicated.
As I'm sitting in the lecture or going through a book that I use to learn I understand the definitions, but when I come to solve the assignments I can't understand anything.

For example, I have this question:

Calculate the sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{n}{2k}$$
Where, $p=\frac{n}{2}$

And I don't really understand how to show such a thing.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I solve this problem
2. How should I think when approaching that kind of questions? Or generally analysis questions. It seems to be very different from what I'm used to.

Comment: Tip: work with small cases. See what happens for $n=2, 4, \ldots$ and find a pattern.

Comment: I've tried, and I can see that it sums up only even numbers and up to some point it the coefficient is zero.
But I don't know what to do with it, nor how to formula an answer.

Comment: There is a broader underlying question.  What do you do if you feel that you are not able to stay afloat in a specific math class.  I advise consulting the professor, perhaps considering dropping the class, and perhaps finding a more introductory text on the same subject that you can master.  If you go that route, then, in the next semester, after you have mastered the introductory text, then you should be ready to start over in the class that formerly gave you trouble.

Comment: I don't think that I should drop the class that quick, it's only the second week.
I think that the problem is that I'm too used to high school math mind set and ill need to understand quickly how to adapt to abstract mathematics.
Maybe a talk with the Prof. could help, but definitely not dropping the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as a combinatorical problem.

You have a binary number of length $n$. Each iteration (in the sum which represents "or") you choose $2k$ of the numbers to be $1$ and the rest $0$. Therefore the sum represents all the binary numbers of length $n$ with evan number of $1$.

The final answer is : all the binary numbers give us $2^n$. Half of them have even number of $1$, and half odd number. So the answer is $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Is there some mathematical way to get to that answer? Or it's just something you have to do in the head?

Comment: It takes some practice ill give you that. But since the semester has only begun, you cant expect to solve this immediately :). Like everything, practice makes perfect.

Comment: Any resource to practice that? my book and lectures seems to be too advanced.
maybe something where the answer shows the way of solving?